# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: html, charts, google-sheets, x-frame-options

I've seen this topic being discussed in general, but I still want to ask for your advice, as I wasn't able to find a reply to my particular case.

I've created a multitude of charts (around 100) using Google Spreadsheets and I'd like to display them on one simple HTML page. In Google Spreadsheets, I used the standard "Publish to the web -> Embed" functionality which produces a snippet like this:

```
<iframe width="600" height="371" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-P_CQWX4Fync2j2g8UVoA2TjXJFA0h83jegn979Jcnw/pubchart?oid=456708661&format=interactive"></iframe>
```

Then I inserted all the snippets into my HTML page and tried to open it in the browser. The result was that 80% of charts were displayed just fine, while the remaining 20% didn't show up. After a reload of the page I got a similar picture, but the combination of displayed / not displayed charts was not the same as before. This repeated at every reload, and number of not displayed charts wasn't constant either.

Looking into the console, I saw that notorious error message

> "Refused to display
>   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-P_CQWX4Fync2j2g8UVoA2TjXJFA0h83jegn979Jcnw/pubchart?oid=456708661&format=interactive'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

I understand what's the purpose of this SAMEORIGIN thing and why it's used by some websites. What I don't understand why it's happening in my case considering:

- Google itself provided us with the embed functionality for charts and
  never explicitly prohibited to embed them into non-Google pages.
- the charts are displayed (or not displayed) just randomly, without any visible consistency.

Has anyone got an idea what's going on and how it may be fixed?

Thanks a lot!